# DbModelBuilder/ModelBuilder .NetCore OnModelCreating and Execute raw sql

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, dbcontext

In .net, we had DBContext class with overriding DbContext method

1. OnModelCreating
   DbModelBuilder.Conventions.Remove
   DbModelBuilder.Conventions.Add

This is not available in .net 6 ModelBuilder. How can we achieve this?

2. Also Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sqlcommand, params) or ExecuteSqlCommandAsync is not available

FYI: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 7.0.2 is being used

Comment: `protected override void ConfigureConventions(ModelConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder)`?

Comment: ModelConfigurationBuilder does not contain conventions either, I am in EntitiyFramework Core 7.0.2

Comment: Check [EF Core 7 what's new](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#model-building-conventions)